# Hibernate : Constraint violation when flushing just before saving

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

EDIT 1 : added hibernate log at the end of the question.

EDIT 2 :
The issue is linked to my database. If I execute the same method from a unit test (unit tests are configured for using another DB), the insert statement pass...
An important thing I didn't write yet : I'm developing a multi-tenant system, based on schema. I currently have 4 schemas corresponding to 4 different clients. I guess I mut have two or more FK constraint badly defiend and pointing to the same table. I'm looking that way for now.

If anyone can think of a method for finding duplicate FK constraint on a field, I'd be glad to read it.

===================================================
Original Post :

Hibernate and JPA are still pretty new for me, so please bear with me...

The following code is OK.

```
    PointAnalyse pointAnalyse = new PointAnalyse();
    em.persist(pointAnalyse);

    // em.flush();

    ResourcesAnalyse resourcesAnalyse = new ResourcesAnalyse();
    resourcesAnalyse.setPointAnalyse(pointAnalyse);

    em.persist(resourcesAnalyse);
```

However, if I un comment the `em.flush()` or perform any other database operation (even a simple select query), I will get a ConstraintViolationException when saving the `resourcesAnalyse` entity :

```
   ERROR: une instruction insert ou update sur la table « ressources_analyse » viole la contrainte de clé
étrangère « fk_ressources_analyse_point_analyse_id »
  Détail : La clé (point_id)=(1722) n'est pas présente dans la table « point_analyse ».]]
```

Translation : FK `point_id` with id `1722` is not present in `point_analyses` table.

If I trace Hibernate queries, I can see that a line with this very ID is indeed inserted before I try to save the `resourceAnalyse` object, so there should not be any error.

Here is the mapping :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "point_analyse")
public class PointAnalyse implements Serializable {

 @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "POINT_ANALYSE_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "POINT_ANALYSE_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "POINT_ANALYSE_ID_GENERATOR")
    @XmlElement
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;

...
}




@Entity
@Table(name = "ressources_analyse")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class ResourcesAnalyse implements Serializable {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "RESSOURCES_ANALYSE_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "RESSOURCES_ANALYSE_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "RESSOURCES_ANALYSE_ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "point_id")
    private PointAnalyse pointAnalyse;

....
}
```

Thank you very much for having read this and if anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the relevant part of the hibernate log :

```
[2016-03-17T08:29:21.494+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1458199761494] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Hibernate:
    select
        nextval ('POINT_ANALYSE_ID_SEQ')]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.496+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1458199761496] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Hibernate:
    insert
    into
        point_analyse
        (accuracy, bearing, distance, gprs_signal, latitude, longitude, max_signal_sat, min_signal_sat, nb_sat, route_analyse_id, speed, tag, timestamp, id)
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.498+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761498] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [1] as [DOUBLE] - [null]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.499+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761499] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [2] as [DOUBLE] - [null]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.499+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761499] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [3] as [DOUBLE] - [null]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.501+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761501] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [null]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.501+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761501] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [5] as [DOUBLE] - [null]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.501+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761501] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [6] as [DOUBLE] - [null]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.502+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761502] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [7] as [DOUBLE] - [null]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.502+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761502] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [8] as [DOUBLE] - [null]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.503+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761503] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [9] as [BIGINT] - [null]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.503+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761503] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [10] as [BIGINT] - [null]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.504+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761504] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [11] as [DOUBLE] - [null]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.504+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761504] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [12] as [VARCHAR] - [null]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.504+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761504] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [13] as [BIGINT] - [null]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.505+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761505] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [14] as [BIGINT] - [1723]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.506+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1458199761506] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Hibernate:
    select
        nextval ('RESSOURCES_ANALYSE_ID_SEQ')]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.507+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1458199761507] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Hibernate:
    insert
    into
        ressources_analyse
        (route_id, point_id, uri_ressource, id)
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.508+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761508] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [null]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.509+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761509] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1723]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.509+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761509] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [null]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.510+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [TRACE] [] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761510] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] [METHODNAME: bind] [[
  binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [113]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.513+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761513] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.514+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761514] [levelValue: 900] [[
  SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.514+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [ERROR] [] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761514] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  L'élément du batch 0 insert into ressources_analyse (route_id, point_id, uri_ressource, id) values (NULL, 1723, NULL, 113) a été annulé. Appeler getNextException pour en connaître la cause.]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.514+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761514] [levelValue: 900] [[
  SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.515+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [ERROR] [] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761515] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  ERREUR: une instruction insert ou update sur la table « ressources_analyse » viole la contrainte de clé
étrangère « fk_ressources_analyse_point_analyse_id »
  Détail : La clé (point_id)=(1723) n'est pas présente dans la table « point_analyse ».]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.515+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [ERROR] [] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761515] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  HHH000315: Exception executing batch [could not execute batch]]]

[2016-03-17T08:29:21.517+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [enterprise_distributedtx.before_completion_excep] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1458199761517] [levelValue: 900] [[
  DTX5014: Caught exception in beforeCompletion() callback:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1882)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:50)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:452)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:854)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:719)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy317.testFk(Unknown Source)
    at com.okina.analysis.__EJB31_Generated__RouteBrutAnalyserService__Intf____Bean__.testFk(Unknown Source)
    at com.okina.resources.RoutesWS.testFk(RoutesWS.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.executeBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:110)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: L'élément du batch 0 insert into ressources_analyse (route_id, point_id, uri_ressource, id) values (NULL, 1723, NULL, 113) a été annulé. Appeler getNextException pour en connaître la cause.
    at
```

Comment: can you add underlying SQL statements logs?

Comment: Did you try without cascading the persist operation on `pointAnalyse`? Since the relation is many-to-one you probably shouldn't cascade deletes either since otherwise you could try to remove a point that is used by another resource.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I added the hibernate logs.

Comment: @Thomas Same thing without the cascading. Cascading wasn't there at first indeed, that was just a leftover from a test I made.

Comment: The only working explanation of this is that your Foreign Key references a different table (since name is the same, the schema problem you described looks possibly)

Comment: Yes, this, or another constraint in another schema referencing the same table and overriding this constraint.

Comment: I dropped all other constraints with the same name, and ended up dropping event the other schemas... no luck. The more I dig, the more I feel that's something as dumb as a case issue...

Comment: Just stumbled on this post again today. Really a pity no answer was provided, got the same issue today :-D

Answer (score 0):

The em.flush() or/and the query forces JPA to execute the SQL statements.

I assume that point_id has a not null constraint. So it tries to do an insert statement with point_id not set.

So you have to make sure that your entity object model is consistent when flushing or executing queries. Or you must remove the not null constraint.

Addionally if there must be not null constraint you should add optional = false to the ManyTo One mapping.

Comment: There's no "not null" constraint on the point_id column... But there should be indeed, there's no way this column can be inserted empty. At the time of insertion, the "point_id" field is not empty (or do not seem to be at least)